# div shows up for a second and hides again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The user clicks on a link and then the div shows up for one second and hides again.
I don´t know what I can do to avoid that it hides again.

**PHP**:

```
echo '<a href="?name='.$name.'&key='.$key.'" onclick="showDesc()">'.$name.'</a>';
```

**JS**:

```
document.getElementById("description").style.visibility="hidden";

function showDesc(){
   document.getElementById("description").style.visibility="visible";
}
```

Comment: There is not enough information here for us to help you work out what's causing the issue. Please provide a link to a working demo, or if that's not possible include all of the *relevant* code so that we can help you find the issue.

Comment: If your browser has a debugger feature it would open with F12. Or else install a debugger like Firebug. And after opening the debugger try clicking the link. There must be an error or unexpected event binding present which is causing the problem. Select the hyperlink using DOM Selector of the Browser debugger and see the Events attached to the hyperlink (probably on the right side of the debugger window).

Answer (score 1):

```js
function showDesc(){
  $("#Div").fadeIn();
   setTimeout(function(){ $("#Div").fadeOut(); }, 2000);
};
```

```css
#Div{
  display:none;
  font-size:20px;
  margin-top:40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="btn" onclick="showDesc();" href="#">click</a>
<div id="Div" style="">Description</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this :
    html + css

```
   #link,#desc{
      display:none;
      font-size:24px;     
    }
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1jquery.min.js"></script>
    <a id="link" href="#">click</a>
    <div id="desc">content</div>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#link").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#desc").fadeIn();
            setTimeout(function(){ $("#desc").fadeOut(); }, 1000);
        });
     });
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use display?

Hide:

```
document.getElementById("description").style.display = "none";
```

Unhide:

```
document.getElementById("description").style.display="block";
```

Can you post your HTML so I can see the problem?